# Need to pass the arguments from the command line while running gatling.sh in Gatling Performance testing

Tags: terminal, performance-testing, gatling, gatling-plugin

I have a scenario where while executing gatling. sh, I need to pass the authorization from the terminal instead of going and changing the situation.scala file always, because authorization is specified only for particular and once a user logs out we need to provide new login Auth key. Basically can we pass the arguments from the command line while running the gatling.sh in Gatling Performance testing. Please, check the simulation.scala file for reference. 
""authorization" -> "Need to pass value from terminal while running the gatling.sh","

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

class RecordedSimulation extends Simulation {

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseURL("baseURL")
        .inferHtmlResources()

    val headers_0 = Map(
        "accept" -> "*/*",
        "accept-encoding" -> "gzip, deflate, br",
        "accept-language" -> "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "access-control-request-headers" -> "access-control-allow-origin,authorization,content-type",
        "access-control-request-method" -> "GET",
        "origin" -> "URL_LINK",
        "user-agent" -> "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36")

    val headers_1 = Map(
        "accept" -> "*/*",
        "accept-encoding" -> "gzip, deflate, br",
        "accept-language" -> "en-US,en;q=0.9",
        "access-control-allow-origin" -> "*",
        **"authorization" -> "Need to pass value from the terminal while running the gatling.sh",**
        "content-type" -> "application/json",
        "origin" -> "ORIGIN_URL",
        "referer" -> "REFERER_URL",
        "user-agent" -> "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36")
```

Comment: Have you read the [docs on passing parameters from the cli to the simulation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/cookbook/passing_parameters/)?

Comment: Thanks for the update and yes, I saw the docs, but I am new to performance testing. So Did not understand where to add that JAVA_OPTS value.

Comment: You're right this isn't well documented... Try to add the `JAVA_OPTS` like described [here](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/general/configuration/#java-opts).

Comment: Thanks again and I am not sure about the launch files in gatling. Like in whihc file to add.

Comment: The launch file is the gatling.sh file, you can either open and edit it with the text editor of your choice or just specify your options before calling the executable. I'll create an answer to go into a little more detail...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://gatling.io/docs/current/cookbook/passing_parameters/), you can pass additional `JAVA_OPTS` either by **editing the launch script** (gatling.sh) or **specifying them in the command line** before calling the launch script.

I'd advise to specify them via the command line as this seems clearer and is explicitly visible.

---

Specifying `JAVA_OPTS` via the command line:

Assuming your on a Unix based system (guessing from your user agent you're on OS X) you can define additional `JAVA_OPTS` before calling gatling.sh like described [here](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/general/configuration/#java-opts):

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dauthorization=foobar" bin/gatling.sh
```

Assuming the value you want to access is a String, you should be able to use the additional value like this:

```
"authorization" -> System.getProperty("authorization")
```

---

You can also edit the launch script itself. Therefore open gatling.sh with the text editor of your choice and add the above `JAVA_OPTS` there.

Comment: Thanks I got it :-)

Comment: Awesome, feel free to [vote up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Your scala file**

`class abcdClass extends Simulation {
    val environment = System.getProperty("environment", "Performance Env.") // here "Performance Env." is default value
    ....
    ....
}`

Console:

**For Linux**

> export JAVA_OPTS="-Denvironment=LoadTest Env"
>
> ./gatling.sh

**For Windows**

> set JAVA_OPTS="-Denvironment=LoadTest Env"
>
> gatling.bat